# put part of the method which returns null in other method

Tags: java

The method `storeData` works fine, but I am trying to put a part of my method in another method `samePosition` to minimize it, but I have the problem that some of its part returns `null`.

I put it in the other method names `samePosition` with return values `Integer` but then I received this error message:

> `This method must return a result of type Integer`

How can I solve this problem?

`storeData` method before minimization:

```
@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response storeData(Data data) {

    String macD = data.getMac();
    int routeD = data.getRoute();
    float latD = data.getLatitude();
    float longD = data.getLongitude();

    // Add the lat and Long to the ArrayList.
    latLongList.add(new LatLong(latD, longD));

////////////I want to put this part in seperate method "samePosition" //////////////
    int size = latLongList.size();
    if (size > 1) {
        ArrayList<Double> array = new ArrayList<>();

        for (int i = 0; i < latLongList.size() - 1; i++) {
            LatLong last = latLongList.get(latLongList.size() - 1);

            double distance = haversineDistance(latLongList.get(i), last);
            array.add(distance);

        }

        ArrayList<Double> distanceRange = new ArrayList<>();

        for (int j = 0; j < array.size(); j++) {

            // Store request in the circumcircle of 4 meter into ArrayList.
            if (array.get(j) < 4) {

                distanceRange.add(array.get(j));
            }
        }

        if (distanceRange.size() == 0) {
            processData(macD, routeD, latD, longD);
        } else {
            return null;
        }

    } else {

        processData(macD, routeD, latD, longD);
    }
//////////////////////until here/////////////////////////
    return Response.status(201).build();
}
```

**Edit:**

storeData:

```
public Response storeData(Data data) {

        String macD = data.getMac();
        int routeD = data.getRoute();
        float latD = data.getLatitude();
        float longD = data.getLongitude();

        // Add the lat and Long to the ArrayList.
        latLongList.add(new LatLong(latD, longD));

        System.out.println("latLondList size: " + latLongList.size());

         int valueReturned =   samePosition(macD, routeD, latD, longD);

        if (valueReturned == -1) {
            return null;
            } else {
                return Response.status(201).build();
            }   
    }
```

samePosition method:

```
private int samePosition(String macD, int routeD, float latD, float longD) {
        int size = latLongList.size();
        if (size > 1) {
            ArrayList<Double> array = new ArrayList<>();

            for (int i = 0; i < latLongList.size() - 1; i++) {
                LatLong last = latLongList.get(latLongList.size() - 1);

                double distance = haversineDistance(latLongList.get(i), last);
                array.add(distance);

            }

            ArrayList<Double> distanceRange = new ArrayList<>();

            for (int j = 0; j < array.size(); j++) {

                // Store request in the circumcircle of 4 meter into ArrayList.
                if (array.get(j) < 4) {

                    distanceRange.add(array.get(j));
                }
            }

            if (distanceRange.size() == 0) {
                processData(macD, routeD, latD, longD);
            } else {
                return -1;
            }

        } else {

            processData(macD, routeD, latD, longD);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Does it have to return an integer for the HTTP status code of the response, or for a different reason?

Comment: What does processData() return? If it just does computation and why do you even have to return anything?

Comment: @steve: no for other reason because some of the part returns `null` and null is Integer type.

Comment: @jags: `proccessData` returns `void` the data is being inserted into the database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the below and modify as needed. Instead of returning 201 as response in all the cases I preferred to return different status code based on whether you processed the data or not.

In your earlier code, the code segment you are trying to extract is returning null from one point and nothing from last else where you are calling processData(..).

```
@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response storeData(Data data) {
  ..
  int status = samePosition(..);
  return Response.status(status).build();
}

private int samePosition(..) {
  int status = 201;
  if() {
    ...
    if (distanceRange.size() == 0) {
      processData(macD, routeD, latD, longD);
    } else {
      status = <Preferred HTTP status code to return for not processing>;
    }
  } else {

  }
  return status;
}
```

Comment: can I use the HTTP status code `208`   for `Preferred HTTP status code to return for not processing` since I want to indicate that the records in the database's tabe  was updated?

Comment: It's entirely driven by your business need. Depends on: If there is no distanceRange how is it to be interpreted? Is it still a success scenario? Do you want to differentiate between processingData and not processing?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of returning null you could return -1 and then check for the value you return being -1.

```
if (valueReturned == -1) {
return null;
} else {
    //continue with method
}
```

The `samePosition()` method should return always an integer:

```
private int samePosition(String macD, int routeD, float latD, float longD) {
    int size = latLongList.size();
    if (size > 1) {
        ArrayList<Double> array = new ArrayList<>();

        for (int i = 0; i < latLongList.size() - 1; i++) {
            LatLong last = latLongList.get(latLongList.size() - 1);

            double distance = haversineDistance(latLongList.get(i), last);
            array.add(distance);

        }

        ArrayList<Double> distanceRange = new ArrayList<>();

        for (int j = 0; j < array.size(); j++) {

            // Store request in the circumcircle of 4 meter into ArrayList.
            if (array.get(j) < 4) {

                distanceRange.add(array.get(j));
            }
        }

        if (distanceRange.size() == 0) {
            processData(macD, routeD, latD, longD);
            return 0;
        } else {
            return -1;
        }

    } else {
        processData(macD, routeD, latD, longD);
            return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: should I put this part in the `storeDate` method or `samePosition` method? and what is `valueReturned` and how to intialize it? what should the return value of the method be  in this case?

Comment: @TheLight  This part goes in the `storeDate` method. `valueReturned` is the return value of the method `samePosition`, you can initialize it when you call that method.

Comment: Please see my edit question code I tried it but I am getting  at this line `samePosition(String macD, int routeD, float latD, float longD)` this error `This method must return a result of type int`

Comment: can you please adjust your idea to my code to understand your point and then update your answer.

Comment: If the method returns int it shoud return it in all cases, see my edited answer.